# TFS web - Test case invitation via email contains wrong link

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, testcase

I have a TFS 2015 with a couple of projects/teams created. We are doing manual tests and I want to send invitations of these manuel tests/suites to the testers.

Exemples:

*- project a / team 1

 - project a / team 2*

Now I want to send an invitation to the testers by using the TFS functionality designed for that, but the TFS generated link is not the right one.

Here are my steps:

- I use a test plan under, for example, **project a / team 1** and go to a
  specific suite - right click - Assign testers to run all tests and
  choose Send email.
- The generated email is containing a link named "View tests"

Now, this links is pointing only to **project** a but not to **project a / team 1**. The team members can open the link, but are, of course,  not seeing the test plan under this path.

Is there a way to get the right link pointing to **project a / team 1** into 
the generated email?

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce your issue on my side. When click the "View tests" in the preview email like the screenshot below, it can point to the correct path. But when click the "View tests" in the email, like outlook, it only point to the project a but not to project / team 1.

[image]

I have submitted a feedback for this issue at website below to track this issue:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/20631/tfs-web-access-test-case-invitation-via-email-cont.html